# Where could the delay in my C# voice chat application over LAN come from, If everything is OK in my test envoronment?

Tags: c#, sockets, delay

I'm using sockets to implement a voice chat application over LAN using C#. Everything is OK, there is a little delay (less than a second) in my test environment which is acceptable but when deployed the delay increases a lot (4-5 seconds). My first guess was the it's duo to a network problem. But I have a D-link DGS-1029a switch for testing and a D-link DGS-1024d switch for deployment. Which I don't know if should make that much of a difference.So my question is, could it be that different behaviors in test and deployment environments come from my code or is it definitely from the network? Thanks a lot.

Edit: I'm using TCP. There is a socket server which keeps an array of clients and basically sends the input from one client to others.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, and the problem description does not provide enough information to make anything but guesses.

That being said, some delays on TCP (if you're using that and not UDP) can be caused by the Nagle algorihm. See the [Socket.NoDelay Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.